# AppMobi .device.getRemoteData is caching

Tags: appmobi

I am using AppMobi.device.getRemoteData method to get data from a webservice which i have hosted on a public server. this webservice returns a random number every time i access it.

When i am testing my application on simulator in XDK ( in chrome ) i get random number every time.

But while testing the application on my iPad using "test anywhere" feature, i get the random value first time and then i get the same value for the subsequent requests.
it seems some things is being cached while testing on iPad which i am not able to figure out.

Any help on this issue will be much appreciated .

i have pasted my code below.

Thanks in advance,
Ashish

```
    getValue = function () {

            AppMobi.device.getRemoteData("http://122.181.151.75/DwebMobile/RandomNumService.svc/GetRandomValue", "GET", "", "success_handler", "error_handler");
        }

  function success_handler(data) {
            var ret = JSON.parse(data);
            var canvas = document.getElementById('id1');
            if (canvas.getContext) {
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                drawShape();
                ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
                ctx.font = 'italic 12px sans-serif';
                ctx.textBaseline = 'top';
                ctx.fillText(ret.d, 22, 70);
            }
            AppMobi.Cache.clearAllCookies();
        }
        function error_handler(data) { alert("error: " + data); }



<body>
        <button id="btnBeep" ontouchstart="getValue();">
            Get Value</button>
        <canvas id="id1"></canvas>
    </body>
```

Comment: There's a possibility that fillText is failing. Have you tried alerting the data to inspect it on device?

Answer (score 1):

We tested a basic random number web service call in App*lab.  AppMobi.device.getRemoteData is NOT caching results, so the error is in your javascript code.

Ian